# Batch-File Make Directory and copy to it

Tags: batch-file

How do I get the copied file to be either copied or moved into the new directory.

```
echo What do you want the folder to be called?
SET /p folderName=
md %folderName%

@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Names.txt) do call :processline "%%a"
pause
goto :eof

:processline
echo line=%*
copy WorkOrderTemplate.xlsm %*.xlsm
goto :eof
```

Comment: What is stopping you from using the variable `foldername` as part of the destination with the `COPY` command?

Comment: I actually tried that but it still shot it all into the current directory. I will try the answer below and see if it works.

Comment: My comment is exactly what the code answer below is referring to.  So if you said you tried it and it didn't work then you didn't do it correctly.

Comment: I would advise that you use `%1` instead of `%*`.

Comment: ..or even better, use `%~1`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend `folderName` to path like this:

```
copy WorkOrderTemplate.xlsm "%folderName%\%*.xlsm"
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks you!! I was missing the  extra % symbol when I attempted to write in the destination.

Comment: @Daniel, so you used the percent symbols when using the `MD` command but forgot to use them with the `COPY` command?

Comment: @Squashman, One of my attempts used %folderName%\ but not the additional %*.xlsm. Also I noticed that when there is a space in the name used for filename it will create two folders. I want to be able to make a single folder while using multiple words with spacing. How would I go about correcting this? Sorry I am doing my best to self teach myself and may not the best at explaining myself. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Daniel, double quotes are used to protect spaces and special characters. Just like you are doing with the `CALL` in your code. It is always a best practice to use quotes regardless of the need them.  So quote your full target path. `"%folderName%\%~1.xlsm"`

Comment: @Squashman Thank you for the advice and quick lesson. I added the quotes as you recommended and also realized that I needed to use quotes earlier in line 3 as well for it to work properly.